# Simple Neural Network numpy error missing "exe"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to run this code for simple Neural Network in python however an error is prompted saying " module 'numpy' has no attribute 'exe' ". I tried searching online but couldn't figure out where the problem is, here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([ [0,0,1],
           [0,1,1],
           [1,0,1],
           [1,1,1] ])
y=np.array([ [1,0,0,1]]).T

class NeuralNetwork(object):
def __init__(self):
    #parameters
    self.inputsize= 3
    self.outputsize= 1
    self.hiddensize=4
    self.learning_rate=0.005
    
    #(3x4) weight matrix from input layer to hidden layer
    self.w0= np.random.randn(self.inputsize, self.hiddensize) 
    #(4x1) weight matrix from hidden layer to output layer 
    self.w1=np.random.randn(self.hiddensize, self.outputsize)

def feedforward(self, x):  
    #forward propegation through the network
    self.z = np.dot(x, self.w0) #dot product with input and first set of weights
    self.z2= self.sigmoid(self.z) #activation function
    self.z3= np.dot(self.z2, self.w1) #dot product with hidden layer and second set of weights
    output= self.sigmoid(self.z3)
    return output
def sigmoid(self, s, deriv=False):
    if (deriv==True):
        return s*(1-s)
    return 1/(1+np.exe(-s))

def backward(self, x, y, output):
    #backward propegation through the network
    self.output_error= y - output #error in output
    self.output_delta= self.output_error * self.sigmoid(output, deriv=True)
    #hidden layer error & delta
    self.z2_error=self.output_delta.dot(self.w1.T)
    self.z2_delta=self.z2_error * self.sigmoid(self.z2, deriv=True)
    #updating weights
    
    self.w0 += self.learning_rate*(x.T.dot(self.z2_delta))
    self.w1 += self.learning_rate*(self.z2.T.dot(self.output_delta))
    
def train(self, x, y):
    output=self.feedforward(x)
    self.backward(x,y, output)
```

so far no errors, but when I run the loop

```
NN=NeuralNetwork()
for i in range(1000):
    NN.train(x,y)
    
print("predicted output:  " + str(NN.feedforward(x)))
```

the error prompted is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-f9adb58b2d65> in <module>
      1 NN=NeuralNetwork()
      2 for i in range(1000):
----> 3     NN.train(x, y)

<ipython-input-39-83a1cb894a8f> in train(self, x, y)
     39 
     40     def train(self, x, y):
---> 41         output=self.feedforward(x)
     42         self.backward(x,y, output)
     43 

<ipython-input-39-83a1cb894a8f> in feedforward(self, x)
     15         #forward propegation through the network
     16         self.z = np.dot(x, self.w0) #dot product with input and first set of weights
---> 17         self.z2= self.sigmoid(self.z) #activation function
     18         self.z3= np.dot(self.z2, self.w1) #dot product with hidden layer and second set of weights
     19         output= self.sigmoid(self.z3)

<ipython-input-39-83a1cb894a8f> in sigmoid(self, s, deriv)
     22         if (deriv==True):
     23             return s*(1-s)
---> 24         return 1/(1+np.exe(-s))
     25 
     26     def backward(self, x, y, output):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in __getattr__(attr)
    217                 return Tester
    218             else:
--> 219                 raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
    220                                      "{!r}".format(__name__, attr))
    221 

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'exe'
```

This is my first post here so I apologize if there are any mistakes

Comment: typo. it should be `np.exp` and not `np.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your `sigmoid` function you are using `np.exe` where it should be `np.exp`

`Numpy` doesn't have any function named `exe` so you are getting `AttributeError`

Answer (score 0):

Try this sigmoid function insted:

```
def sigmoid(self, s, deriv=False):
    if (deriv==True):
        return s*(1-s)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-s))
```